# Line stereo/2-channel recording

Tags: android, hardware, audio-recording

Are there any Android devices available that support multi-channel (stereo) recording via line-in?

With the devices I tested (Nexus 4, HTC Buzz, Motorola Xoom ..), it is possible to set AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO, but I only receive one active channel.

Is this a gerneral limitation of Android due to licensing issues or is this depending on the manufacturer/hardware, i.e. there is only one A/D converter for input or some such?

Any experiences, thoughts or ideas on this topic?

Comment: Most of the Sony XPeria devices released in the last couple of years supports stereo recording. That's from the built-in microphones though, not via linein. It might have been necessary to set an an audio parameter on some devices, but on the P/U/Sola/Go models it should suffice to request 2 channels (the exception is the XPeria P when using the CAMCORDER audio source, which will give you dual mono from the primary mic to avoid picking up noise from the camera objective mechanics which are located really close to the secondary mic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any Android devices available that support multi-channel (stereo) recording via line-in?

Concerning most smartphones and tablets factory-equipped with Android there is an unpleasant answer: No.

Why not? Because these devices (and BTW also all iPhones) use the 4pin TRRS-3.5mm-plug to connect headphones and/or microphone to the device. The four pins are used for T) left speaker, R1) right speaker, R2) ground for speaker and microphone, and finally S) monophonic microphone.

**UPDATE:** When I added in Dec 2013 that "the invention of the TRRRS (I would suggest to call it "T3RS") plug would solve the problem" I couldn't know that Sony was already working on that and presented the "STM-10" stereo microphone with exactly that T3RS-plug in Feb 2014.

[image: T3RS plug]

> Is this a gerneral limitation

Yes, but simply due to the hardware audio plug, not due to licensing.

In 2014 there came very few Android smartphones that have the T3RS-plug with external stereo input: Xperia Z2, Z2 tablet, Z3

As a side note, the gain of the input amplifier is adjusted to microphone output level and not to line level (e.g. of a CD-player).

Comment: I'm not sure this necessarily answers the question. You answer assumes freiform is using the 1/8" headphone jack. What about through a USB device?

Comment: I did ask specifically about line-in, so Hartmut's reply is spot on. On the other hand, USB would be a viable alternative

Comment: As Android is a software platform and runs on a wide variety of hardware, it's really not possible to conclusively say that there are no devices with this capability.

Comment: Your mistake is in assuming that android is limited to phones and tablets.  It isn't - it's a piece of software, and an extremely portable one at that.  You have no idea what range of special purpose devices run it.  Allowing for such uses is why the API supports something *typical* hardware does not.  And technically, any device with USB host could, after a software rebuild.

Comment: Specific example: the Eeepc-701

Comment: https://www.olimex.com/Products/OLinuXino/A10S/ is factory-equipped with Android 4.0.4 and has LINE_IN hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Olimex OLinuXino A10S https://www.olimex.com/Products/OLinuXino/A10S/ has a LINE_IN connector.  I haven't found out how to access it yet, but it is there!