# Android: Is there any way I can connect an external microphone(s) to my device and then access them?

Tags: android, microphone

As the title says, I am looking to connect one or a few microphones to my android device and then collect data from them as they record. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

How are you going to connect them? Can you not use the standard [Audio Capture guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html)?

This other question may help you [android mediaRecorder.setAudioSource failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782786/android-mediarecorder-setaudiosource-failed)

Comment: What I would like to do is essentially have one microphone at the top of my device, one on each side, and the one built in. I was just curious if it would be possible to get a splitter and connected 3 of them together and plug it into the headphone jack of my device.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do it in the simple way you asked. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812579/line-stereo-2-channel-recording) for the reason. What you can do is build a device that record from all the microphones, and then send the data to the Android device, via USB or BT or whatever.