# How can I most directly record an MP3 or WAV to my phone's voicemail greeting

Tags: android, mp3, record, voicemail

This seems like the simplest question, but all my attempts have been unsuccessful, and all my searching has been unhelpful.

I like to make custom voicemail greetings.  Rather than simply talk into the mic like most people, I like to record into a quality mic, process them, add effects, etc and save them as a MP3 or WAV.

The problem is, the only way I've found so far to transfer the greeting to my phone, is to call my voicemail and when recording the greeting, hold the phone up to my pc speakers.  Obviously the quality loss is tremendous.

I thought I should be able to just plug a cable from the headphone jack of my pc, into the audio jack of the phone, and play it directly into the phone when the voicemail is recording, however I've tried tons of cables and tons of software and can't get it to work.

Is there any way to play an audio file directly into the phone, to record the voicemail greeting?  Phone is a galaxy S1, carrier is Tmobile.

Comment: Just an update.  I can plug in a standard mic into the 3.5mm connector on the phone and record from it just fine.  I can get a audio signal from the headphone out of the PC just fine.  Logically it seems just plug a cable from the headphone out of the PC to the audio in of the phone, but it simply doesn't work.  I've tried every pinout combination imagineable, and even tinkered with various series and parallel resistors thrown in as well.  I just can't get the pc audio out, to play well with the phone audio in.

Comment: I think I found a thread which partially addresses the issue, but not enough for me to get it to work.  Apparently I may need a voltage divider between the pc headphone output and the android phone input.  Haven't been able to figure out how to do this though, heres the thread.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24774483/audio-input-through-headphone-jack-in-android