# Audio Line-in support in smartphones

Tags: android

Does anyone know if any of the latest smartphones provide a audio line-in support?
Am aware that this question has been addressed earlier as well but it has been a while since the last query on this and also the smartphones has evolved so much.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Please use https://android.stackexchange.com for non-programming Android questions, at least those that are on-topic for that site.

Comment: search the Android developer site for API support for audio input.  If you find it, write a program that uses it and see if it works.

Comment: If this is a generic "Is there hardware somewhere that does this?" question then this is not the right place for the question.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completion, I will answer my own query. After googling for few days, I conclude that none of the existing Android phones in the market provide line-in support. This is more of a hardware restriction.
[Line stereo/2-channel recording](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812579/line-stereo-2-channel-recording?lq=1) has detailed explanation.